# traitCollectionDidChange don't trigger properly in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios-darkmode, uitraitcollection

I use `traitCollectionDidChange` in my `swift` classes to successfully trigger `dark mode` changes. Like this:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    toggleDarkMode()
}
```

Works great. It triggers every time I switch between modes. But for my `objective-c` classes the `delegate` don't trigger when switching between dark and light mode. Code looks similar:

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [self toggleDarkMode];
}
```

I can only get it to trigger by going out of the `view`, then back in again. Is there something I have missed in the `objective-c` code?

Comment: Did you or anyone else find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I get it working calling super:

```
 - (void) traitCollectionDidChange: (UITraitCollection *) previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange: previousTraitCollection];
    [self toggleDarkMode];
}
```